# Magento 2.4.5 layout handle template variables passing null values

Tags: email-templates, magento2.4.5

I am working on custom email template layout. In this template.html file I use custom layout handle with custom object variables as shown as below.

{{layout handle="custom_layout_handle" quote=$quote }}

"custom_layout_handle" contains custom phtml file where I try to get quote object but it gives me type of null.

In my send mail class file. I pass variables using DataObject() class too., but it still not working.

Here, I share my code

```
$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

$vars = [ 'quote' => $quote ];
$transportObject = new DataObject($vars);
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$transportBuilder = $om->get('\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder');
$state = $om->get('\Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface');

$storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

$builder = $transportBuilder
        ->setFrom(['email'=>"first.last@test.com", 'name'=>"Main"])
        ->setTemplateOptions(([
            'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
            'store' => $ruleQuote->getStoreId()
        ]))
        ->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

 $builder->addTo("test-email@test.com");
    $transport = $builder->setTemplateIdentifier($schedule->getTemplateId(), $storeScope)->getTransport();
    $transport->sendMessage();
    $state->resume();
```

Thanks.

Comment: check the object of quote you are passing to html have data or null or please update you question with code

Comment: in same template I pass $quote.getCustomerFirstname(), it gives me proper customer name, but when it comes through layout handler, it passes null object @Mehran

Comment: you have to pass template variable like this ->setTemplateVars([
                    'quote'  => $quote
                ])

Comment: I tried it so far, still it does not work for me.

Comment: do you get something from quote in your html file? maybe the quote object your are passing is null

Comment: Can you please add the file from where you are getting $quote?
I will help you then

Answer (score 1):

**You need to pass quote_id and load that Quote using quote id.**

```
{{layout handle="custom_layout_handle" quote_id=$quoteId }}
```

Comment: I also tried this one. It does not work for me.

Comment: in your phtml file use $block->getQuoteId() to get quote_id